# WCF Service Reference different when using Metro App vs Console App

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-metro

I have a service that has the following method to upload a file to the server:

```
public void uploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
{
    FileStream targetStream = null;
    Stream sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;

    //Tempdir
    string uploadFolder = @"C:\upload\";

    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);
    using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        // Read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks
        const int bufferLen = 65000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
        {
            //save to output stream
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        targetStream.Close();
        sourceStream.Close();
    }
}
```

When I made a test console app and added a service reference to this service, I was able to call it using `myServiceProxy.uploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)`.

The issue is that as soon as I tried to add a service reference to my metro app project, I lost the ability to call `uploadFile` and can only call `uploadFileAsync` which I haven't even implemented.

Is there any way to use the regular `uploadFile` method from the wcf service on a metro app?

One of the main issues is that I have a `MessageContract` set up for `RemoteFileInfo` which contains 2 message headers and 1 `MessageBodyMember` which I am unable to even access on the metro app but I can access just fine on the console app.

Comment: You do not need to implement `uploadFileAsync` on the WCF service, it is automatically handled. As long as you implemented `uploadFile`, you can call `uploadFileAsync`.

Comment: I guess at this point im trying to figure out why my 2 message header strings in my remotefileinfo arent being exposed at all when used in a metro app, but i can reference them just fine in a regular console app